# How to create ND.nd folder with .nds files

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, network-dataset, closest-facility, closest-distance

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.1. When using Network Analysis, I have to import Network Data Source which in _ND.nd format(i.e. XXXX_road_ND.nd). There are six files within the .nd folder with .nds file extensions(i.e. XXXX_ND_ln_blob.nds / XXXX_ND_ln_blobx.nds / XXXX_ND_ln_desc.nds / XXXX_ND_ln_descx.nds / XXXX_ND_ln_schema.nds / XXXX_ND_nd_schema.nds). These files was created by my previous colleagues that nobody knows how it created now.

Now I have to create the same format files by network shpfile, and I cannot find any information about it. How is it created?